# Looking for silverlight tree control sample with binding to table

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I can't find an example of a silverlight 2 tree control that is bound to a database table. I have a table with ID and ParentID columns and I use it to populate a tree control in windows forms. I want to do the same with a silverlight tree control but I can't find any examples on how to do this. Most of the samples have the nodes hard coded. I don't need any advice on how to wcf the data table, I know that part really well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with the tree control myself, but I did a quick google, and found the following site [Populating Silverlight TreeView from WCF Service with LINQ to SQL](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/silverlight/general/populating-treeview.aspx)

It does however make use of custom classes to store the data and then makes use of LINQ to SQL to extract data from your data tables to manually construct the tree view.

Hope this helps